# Getting the lowest and highest value from integers without using arrays?

Tags: java, loops, integer

I'm trying to write a class which reads 5 integers from the user and returns the highest and lowest value back. This must be done using loops and without using arrays and Integer.MIN.Value/Integer.MAX.Value. I've already succeeded writing code that gets 5 integers from the user and returns the highest value but I just can't get both the highest and the lowest value returned in the same class.

Here is the code I mentioned above:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ovning_321 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number;
            int max = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x<5; x++){ 
                 System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 
                 number = input.nextInt(); 

                 if (number > max){ 
                      max = number;  
                 }              
             }                  
             System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can or can't use `MIN_VALUE`? If you already have logic that keeps track of the highest value seen, how could you modify it to add something that keeps track of the lowest value seen?

Comment: +1 for decent try on your own and getting max almost right on your own

Comment: what if all the inputs are negative integers? then this will incorrectly give 0 as a max

Comment: @underbar that's why the user is here asking for help on SO

Comment: @ no_answer_not_upvoted
But max is right? I mean, application does what I want it to do.

@ underbar
Should have mentioned that negative inputs are not allowed by the user. This should have been prompted in the System.out.print.

Comment: @Dinco max is almost right. the problem with your max is that it cannot work for negative inputs. my answer below works for both positive and negative inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ovning_321 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number;
            int max = 0;
            int min = 0;

                  for (int x = 0; x<5; x++){ 
                        System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 
                        number = input.nextInt(); 

                        if (x == 0 || number > max){ 
                            max = number;  
                        }               
                        if (x == 0 || number < min){ 
                            min = number;  
                        }               
                  }                 
                  System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
                  System.out.println("Lowest value: " + min);
            }
     }
```

Comment: what if user enters -4 -5 -3 -2 0 -4 -7, max will be -4

Comment: @underbar i don't see how. iteration 1 max will be -4; iteration 2 max will not change; iteration 3 max will be -3 because x is not 0 and -3 > max

Comment: i dont think it would, as the if statement changes max if the input number is larger than it.

Comment: output: `$ javac Ovning_321.java`
`$ java Ovning_321`
Give me an integer: -4
Give me an integer: -5
Give me an integer: -3
Give me an integer: -2
Give me an integer: 0
Highest value: 0
Lowest value: -5

Comment: i meant the second -4, that was a bad example. Try -1 -2 0 -4 -5

Comment: @dcaswell dude just try it out, it isn't rocket science .. max and min both will be -4 because the `x == 0` condition will be triggered .. or am i missing something?

Comment: 0 > -4 or am i missing something?

Comment: @underbar i am not sure what's your issue.. it feels like a terrible waste of time to try your suggestions: `$ java Ovning_321
Give me an integer: -1
Give me an integer: -2
Give me an integer: 0
Give me an integer: -4
Give me an integer: -5
Highest value: 0
Lowest value: -5
`

Comment: @dcaswell i don't see why.. first element both if statements will fire and set it to first element

Comment: ahh my mistake in my code I had `if (number == 0 || number > max)` which was the source of my errors. sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @no_answer: Regarding the comment right above mine: If you update your answer people will be able to change their incorrect vote.

Comment: @dcaswell thanks. the downvote / point loss in itself doesn't bother me. it just got frustrating trying to explain and not having people see the point despite it being compilable+runnable code.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now... to 99%. Lets' say that users are allowed to input negative values, why does the "x == 0" allow that? I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: @Dinco The logic works for positive and negative values. "x == 0" means that we are seeing the first value input. If it is the first value then we **blindly** pick it as the current max and the current min. When "x != 0" it means that we are seeing the second, third or later values. In that case we compare it with the current max and current min before accepting it as the new max or new min. Makes sense?  "x" is the counter of how many values, not the value itself.

Comment: I understand it fully now! Thank you kind sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just repeat your max logic for min?

```
public class Ovning_321 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 

        number = input.nextInt();
        int max = number;
        int min = number;

              for (int x = 0; x<4; x++){ 
                    System.out.print("Give me an integer: "); 
                    number = input.nextInt(); 

                    if (number > max){ 
                        max = number;  
                    }

                    if (number < min){ 
                        min = number;  
                    } 
              }                 
              System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
              System.out.println("Lowest value: " + min);
        }
 }
```

Note that max and min are initially set to the first number that the user enters, so there will be no false 0's and no need to `MAX_INT` or `MIN_INT`. This in turn makes the loop run once less so terminate at `i == 4` instead of 5.

Comment: -1 for misunderstanding my answer despite multiple attempts to explain it

Comment: isn't SO supposed to help cure misunderstanding rather than punish those who experience it?

Comment: sometimes it is the best way to vent when someone not only misunderstood but also downvoted and then didn't understand until the third attempt.

Comment: SO isn't for venting. I made a mistake, realized it, and corrected it. No need for emotion. No need for name calling. Try to keep that in mind next time you meet a "moron".

Comment: Also -1 for a working answer? now this is just getting rediculous

Comment: "-1 for a working answer" .. see how it feels?  i deleted my "moron" comment, but it was intended for the downvote of a perfectly good answer, and not for the lack of understanding. anyway, that comment is gone. i have more downvotes than you for a better answer, and that's about as fair as life gets on SO.