# How do I find the lowest score entered using for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need this code to print out the lowest score entered and I'm sitting here for hours and I can't figure out how to do it.I know how to make it using arrays but I need to use for loops.Do you have any hints?

Example output:

```
  How many scores? 3
  Enter score 1: 90
  Enter score 2: 80
  Enter score 3: 100
  Lowest score is 80
```

My code:

```
  int score,numScore,count;


  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("How many scores? ");
  numScore = keyboard.nextInt();

  for(count = 1; count <= numScore; count++){
     System.out.print("Enter score " + count + ":");
     score = keyboard.nextInt();
  }
```

Comment: You know, it might help to at least tell us what language you're using, don't you think?

Comment: It's a java.Sorry about that.

Comment: This question already has an answer [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435242/getting-the-lowest-and-highest-value-from-integers-without-using-arrays)

Comment: thank you so much guys.It's really simple solution.I was killing myself because I couldn't come up with anything. Definitely need to practice a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the lowest score in a variable and update it every time the lower score is encountered:

```
int lowestScore = 100;

for(count = 1; count <= numScore; count++){
    System.out.print("Enter score " + count + ":");
    score = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(score < lowestScore){
        lowestScore = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: High five on the exact same code (almost) only 13 seconds apart.

Comment: Well, there are not that many options :) Variable naming is also quite standard ha-ha.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a variable that you compare against with each keyboard input.

```
int lowestScore = 100000;
for(count = 1; count <= numScore; count++){
     System.out.print("Enter score " + count + ":");
     score = keyboard.nextInt();

     if (score < lowestScore) {
          lowestScore = score;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a variable to find the lowest score like this

```
    int lower = -1;
```

Inside for loop

```
    if(lower == -1) {
      lower = score;
    } else if(score < lower) {
      lower = score;
    }
```

Finally lower has the required value

Answer (score 0):

Added 3 lines

```
int score,numScore,count;
int minimum;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many scores? ");
numScore = keyboard.nextInt();

for(count = 1; count <= numScore; count++){
     System.out.print("Enter score " + count + ":");
     score = keyboard.nextInt();
     if (count == 1) minimum = score;
     if (score < minimum) minimum = score;

}
```